# create spaces between image and string in spannable setSpan

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

I need to place an image and string in the center of the button. Need to create spaces between them.
a      Hello (%1$d)

My code:

```
String textValue = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_text);
            final Spannable buttonLabel = new SpannableString(String.format(textValue, 2));
            //buttonLabel.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.hello_imagel,
                   // ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            mButton.setText(buttonLabel);
```

I need give spaces between the image and the text. I tried giving spaces in the strings.xml but it doesn't display the spaces. After adding the below xml, the image is to the left and the string is in the center. I want the image and string to be in center with few spaces between image and string

xml:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#2A2A2A"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/hello_image1"
    android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Any answers for my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to show an icon inside a string you can add drawable to your button.
i.e. an icon at the left side of the text:

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
     android:drawablePadding="20dp">
```

where @drawable/icon is your icon and 20dp is padding between icon and text

Shure you can do the same from code - take a look at setCompoundDrawables and setCompoundDrawablePadding

Comment: It appears that you are trying to add image at zero position in spannable string, so you can remove your code and add this image in xml file the same way as I wrote above.

Comment: I tried your idea but the padding doesn't work. the button gravity is set to center. I have added my xml to the question.

Comment: yes I tried 20dp and also 50dp. It is always in the left corner

Comment: Ah... you've modified the question. I thought that you wanted the image to be at the left edge. The code I posted won't help.
Try this (extend ImageSpan class and override several methods): http://ravenandroid.blogspot.com/2013/07/modifiable-image-span.html

Answer (score 0):

sorry to be late, I hope this method helps you, is on kotlin:

```
fun setLeftIcon(roundButton: RoundButton, iconId: Int) = with(roundButton) {
  if (iconId == DEFAULT_IMAGE_ID) return
  val currentText = text.toString()
  // The spaces are a workaround to add some space between the image and the text
  val buttonLabel = SpannableString("   $currentText")
  buttonLabel.setSpan(
    ImageSpan(context, iconId),
    0,
    1,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
  )
  text = buttonLabel
}
```